# Converting color bmp to grayscale bmp?

Tags: c++, c, bmp

I am trying to convert a colored BMP file to gray-scale BMP. The input bmp is 24 bit and I am producing the same 24 bit bmp at the output, only this time in gray-scale.

The code I am using is

```
for(int x = 0; x < max; x++)
{
    int lum;
    lum = (r[x]*0.30) + (g[x]*0.59) + (b[x]*0.11);
    r[x] = lum;
    g[x] = lum;
    b[x] = lum;
}
```

The `r`, `g`, `b` arrays are the RGB color components and I have them in a `char *r,*g,*b`.

For some reasons I am not getting a clean output. I am attaching the output I am getting with this question, its patchy and contains white and black areas at palces. So what am I doing wrong here?

1. Is it due to data loss in calculationg of lum or is there something wrong in storing int as a char?
2. Can gray-scale bmp not be 24 bit? or is it something wrong in the way I am storing rgb values after conversion?

Any help in this will be much appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: you can add your code? how you load the image into matrix and doing this process and save it? thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These should really be `unsigned char`; if `char` happens to be signed on your platform, then this code won't do what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clamp the output of your calculation to be in [0,255].  Your calculation looks ok, but it's always good to be sure.

Also make sure that the r, g, b arrays are `unsigned char`.  You can get away with a lot of signed/unsigned mixing in int (due to 2's complement overflow covering the mistakes) but when you convert to float the signs must be right.

Comment: Clamping ought to be unnecessary in this instance.  Even if all three components are full-scale, the sum should never be bigger than full-scale (+ fractional error due to floating-point representation).  Conversion back to int always truncates toward zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not need the clamping but making my RGB channles as RGB worked great!!! Thanks a whole lot.